# How to track eyes using Kinect SDK?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, eye-tracking

The requirement is to define a rectangle around each eye in 3D space.
There should be a way to track eyes using the Microsoft Kinect SDK.
According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx#ID4EWF)

> The Face Tracking SDK uses the Kinect coordinate system to output its
>   3D tracking results.  The origin is located at the camera’s optical
>   center (sensor), Z axis is pointing towards a user, Y axis is pointing
>   up.  The measurement units are meters for translation and degrees for
>   rotation angles.

Adding

```
...
Debug3DShape("OuterCornerOfRightEye", faceTrackFrame.Get3DShape()
    [FeaturePoint.OuterCornerOfRightEye]);
Debug3DShape("InnerCornerRightEye", faceTrackFrame.Get3DShape()
    [FeaturePoint.InnerCornerRightEye]);
Debug3DShape("InnerCornerLeftEye", faceTrackFrame.Get3DShape()
    [FeaturePoint.InnerCornerLeftEye]);
Debug3DShape("OuterCornerOfLeftEye", faceTrackFrame.Get3DShape()
    [FeaturePoint.OuterCornerOfLeftEye]);
...
private void Debug3DShape(string s, Vector3DF v)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(s + " X " + v.X + " Y " + v.Y + " Z " + v.Z);
}
```

to CreateResult() in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking prints

```
OuterCornerOfRightEye X -0.05728126 Y 0.04850625 Z -0.1144406
InnerCornerRightEye X -0.01584376 Y 0.04850625 Z -0.1279687
InnerCornerLeftEye X 0.01584374 Y 0.04850625 Z -0.1279687
OuterCornerOfLeftEye X 0.05728124 Y 0.04850625 Z -0.1144406
```

when the SDK starts tracking a face.
I should be able to use these coordinates to paint a box around each eye but 
the Z coordinate should probably be closer to 1.0, not -0.1.. or -0.2.. (based on my setup) so I don't trust the numbers.
Is the XYZ supposed to be the location of the FeaturePoint in 3D space relative to the sensor?
Do I misunderstand the Kinect coordinate system?
Am I using the Kinect SDK incorrectly?
Does it matter that I am using an Xbox 360 Kinect Sensor? 
(Microsoft does not guarantee full compatibility for Kinect for Windows applications and the Xbox 360 Kinect Sensor)

**Edit: Adding this**

```
if (trackSucceeded) {
    ...
    if (headPointsObj != null) 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
            DebugHeadPoint(i, headPointsObj.Points);
}
private void DebugHeadPoint(int i, Vector3DF[] points) {
    if (points == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("points");
    Debug.WriteLine("HeadPoint[" + i + "] X " + points[i].X + 
        " Y " + points[i].Y + 
        " Z " + points[i].Z);
}
```

to FaceTracker.cs::Track() prints this

```
HeadPoint[0] X 0.01227657 Y -0.2290326 Z 1.319978
HeadPoint[1] X 0.00613283 Y -0.02143053 Z 1.280334
HeadPoint[0] X 0.003939687 Y -0.2297621 Z 1.319813
HeadPoint[1] X -0.003732742 Y -0.02388078 Z 1.277723
...
```

These numbers seem correct based on the setup.
The FeaturePoints print only once but the HeadPoints print continuously while trackSucceeded.
Are FeaturePoint values relative to the HeadPoint?

Comment: Outside of face tracking, XYZ is measured in millimeters from the Kinect origin.  I would guess the values are the same, though they may be the difference from a facial point.  I've not delt directly with the face tracker before to be sure.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx#ID4EWF) _The measurement units are meters_.

Comment: Indeed, the seem to be in meters for the face tracker.  The regular depth [coordinate system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) reports in millimeters and I hadn't tracked down the link you posted above.  How far away from the Kinect are you sitting?  Grab a ruler! :)

Comment: I notice you got an answer to this on MSDN. It seems like the answer should be crossposted here for reference, but I'd feel odd doing it myself, as I didn't answer it. Perhaps the OP should? Not sure of the etiquette on this.

Comment: @MikePrecup: I made a suggestion to the OP at MSDN to post a link here.

Comment: @jacknad I posted my comment below.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per our conversation on MSDN forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93046062-05fe-4beb-9d69-94a4f004fb7b/how-to-track-eyes-using-kinect